# Excitation and de excitation...

Tags: physical-chemistry

I had learn that whenever there is an excitation  in an atom, it is single step that is excitation takes place in only one step. 
On ther other hand whenwhere there is de excitation  it is multiple stepped that is de excitation takes place in multiple steps. 
If this is right,i wants to why is this.?

Comment: Could you expand a little bit? The typos make it specially hard to understand what you're saying here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The excitation typically is due to an absorbed photon. This is a one-step process. The de-excitation will usually proceed by several one-step processes, some of which will emit a photon and some will be "internal conversion" and thus without emission.

Note that an excited state can very well absorb another photon to reach an even higher state - but this is unlikely, because you typically have many atoms in the ground state and few in the excited state.